# NodeJS Shortener Code Don't Work at Chromium

Tags: javascript, node.js, mime

I want to make shorter my code. In this case I maked this

```
const s_html = 'text/html';
const s_png = 'image/png';
const s_jpg = 'image/jpg';
const s_jpeg = 'image/jpeg';
const s_css = 'text/css';
const s_js = 'text/javascript';
```

My Shortener Function

```
function datatype(file, filetype) {
  fs.readFile(file, function(err,data){res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': filetype}); res.write(data); res.end();})
  }
```

After, I allowed to make this

```
case '/static/toolkit.js':
datatype("./static/toolkit.js", "s_js");
break;
```

After run my code, My website don't show style but css code is available in Inspect>Source

There is no wrong or missing something. Later on I connect my website on Firefox and it was seamless.

So what's the problem there? Is it problem in my browser? Because I use ungoogled chromium in debian

Comment: After the first time you declare and assign a value a constant,  in your case `s_html`, you can't assign another value to override it, nor you can re-declare the same variable again as you have it done 5 times more.

Comment: Unless the variable `res` is global, you will get an error here `res.writeHead`.
You might need to add `res` as a parameter to your function `datatype`.

Comment: But code working on Firefox and in chromium my css code is valid like others. Also I think it's just a browser problem. I'll check with another pc.

Comment: It may not be as compatible as you think it is. Also, for some properties you need to add a browser denominator. For example, for Firefox you add `-webkit` or `-moz`, for IE you add `-ms`, for Chrome and safari you might add `-webkit`.